# Retrieving Longlat saved in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-maps

Im doing a android app that lets waiting commuters hitch on those who have private vehicles. I have 2 apps, which is for passenger and the other one is for driver.My question is how can i retrieve the location of the passenger which is saved in firebase then display it in my drivers map.

This is my firebase database structure

```
 TRANSACTION

 - Ag6AVcsrt4d4npaoBJfVO91Dffe2
     - latlng
         -latitude: 10.287503
         -longitude: 123.863112
```

and this in my map

```
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }  else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

**I tried to retrieve it like this**

```
    `  btnRetrieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            databasePassenger.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
               @Override
                     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                     LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(
                                        dataSnapshot.child("TRANSACTION").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("latitude").getValue(),
                                        dataSnapshot.child("TRANSACTION").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("longitude").getValue()
                                        );


                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(newLocation)
                                    .title(dataSnapshot.getKey()));
                        }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                            }
                        });`
```

Comment: Please show your Firebase database structure and any code that you have as a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 please help me, i already put the firebase structure and some codes

Comment: Do you have any Firebase code yet? Like getting the reference for the `TRANSACTION` element?

Comment: @cricket_007 please see above, i added how i tried to retrieve. Thank you!

Comment: And where do you assign `databasePassenger`?